# NSString makes my app crash... maybe

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nslog

Huge and strange problem:
I take pictures and save them inside my app with a name I decided (day+random number), and I store the address of the picture in my "imagePath" NSString variable.
Till the end of this method i can access the content of "imagePath, which is a global variable; but when I try to use it in another method, I should save this address in a sqlite database, it give me EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
Well, also if I try to see its content with "NSLog(@"%@",imagePath);" it crashs.
Some ideas?

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    int r = arc4random() % 9999;
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSString *photoName = [dateNameFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    photoName = [photoName stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", r]];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@.png", photoName]];

    UIImage *picture = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    // ----- CODE FOR SCALE THE IMAGE ----- //

    // ----- ----- - END CODE - ----- ----- //

    NSData *webData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(picture);
    CGImageRelease([picture CGImage]);
    [webData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"%@", imagePath);
    imgPicker = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that this:

```
imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@.png", photoName]];
```

assigns `imagePath` to an autoreleased object. This means that it will be released as part of the `NSAutoreleasePool` drain that occurs at the end of the cycle of the event loop.

Since you don't create the memory *but you want it to hang around*, you have to `retain` it:

```
[imagePath retain];
```

What you need to determine is when this piece of retained memory can be **released**. Since we don't know exactly how your app works, the decision is up to you. If you're calling this method more than once, you'll probably want to release it as such:

```
if (imagePath) {
    [imagePath release];
}
imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@.png", photoName]];
[imagePath retain];
```

If this object should only survive as long as your picker controller, you should release it in the `dealloc` method:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [imagePath release];
    // Other releases
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Otherwise, if this should survive for the lifetime of your application, don't worry about releasing it in `dealloc`. (But you should still release it prior to assigning it, if you're assigning it more than once.) The memory will be reclaimed by the OS when your application terminates.

Comment: Great! That was perfect! Thanks a lot. Just one more thing: how can I set an image to a UIImage using the complete path of the image? (this just to intend --> /Users/Sk*****/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/15977219-DEFE-407A-BB80-72E188E18DD2/Documents/20-10-20111746.png )

Comment: You should ask that in a separate question. I can answer it, but the comments section isn't the place. :)

Answer (score 1):

You may try this...

```
imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@.png", photoName]];

[imagePath retain];

// Your code//

[webData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"%@", imagePath);

[imagePath release];
```

Comment: Release in dealloc not in same method.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The OP is storing **imagePage** as an instance variable so that it can be used in other methods. If you release it here right after creating it, the object could be deallocated, leaving the ivar in a corrupted state. Also @Ishu, if this method is being called multiple times, leaving the **release** call in dealloc could result in memory leaks.

Comment: @craig then it hould be like [imagePath release];[imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@.png", photoName]];

[imagePath retain];

Answer (score 1):

Set [NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled), [MallocStackLogging](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MallocStackLogging), and [guard malloc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html) in the debugger.  Then, when your App crashes, type this in the gdb console:

```
(gdb) info malloc-history 0x543216
```

Replace `0x543216` with the address of the object that caused the crash, and you will get a much more useful stack trace and it should help you pinpoint the exact line in your code that is causing the problem.

[See this article for more detailed instructions.](http://www.codza.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-on-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

The value you store in imagePath isn't owned by you. From `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` your getting an autoreleased object. You have retain it. (Btw: Are you developing under ios5?)

Answer (score 0):

since imagePath is global variable. then you can acces it any where in class but what happens when you store some value at that time you are not retaining it.

after goes off from the ,method where it got value , it goes release. so use retain on it.

after this line

```
imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@.png", photoName]];

[imagePath retain];
```

and release it in dealloc not in any method while you are not calling retain any other time.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *imgPathWithOutDir = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@" %@.png", photoName];
    imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imgPathWithOutDir];

    UIImage *picture = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    // ----- CODE FOR SCALE THE IMAGE ----- //

    // ----- ----- - END CODE - ----- ----- //

    NSData *webData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(picture);
    CGImageRelease([picture CGImage]);
    [webData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"%@", imagePath);
    [imgPathWithOutDir release];
    imgPicker = nil;
```